# What does Vo stands for?

Tags: oop, activerecord, orm

I found this abbreviation in many projects it is a folder referring to database models in an active record context

but What does it mean exactly ?

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as off topic, was helpful to me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

VO normally stands for Value Object.

In Domain Driven Development (DDD), value objects represent one or more pieces of information, but do not contain an identity.  For instance, an Address object containing street address, city, state, and zip would be considered a value object.

This site can provide more info: http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-entities-and-value-objects.aspx

Comment: It does not explain what "do no contain an identity" means?

Comment: I think what is meant by "do no contain an identity" is that comparisons of two VOs are structural, meaning the two objects are equal if all their properties are equal. Compare that to each object having a unique id and `objectA == objectB` only if they are truly the same space in memory (reference). Sounds like a VO is another name for a struct or immutable container.

Answer (score 8):

VO stands for Value Object. The difference from normal objects is that value objects' only purpose is to store values in a convenient way. In short that means that a value object just contains a bunch of properties and no methods.